# Send data from Tablayout to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

In my project I have **Tablayout**  .

when I select one tab I want to send his position to the fragment .

**Note** (Tablayout and fragment are in the same actitvity)

I try this code

**activity**

```
 private int tab_idd;


 tab.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    tab_idd = getTabId(tab.getPosition());


                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });


        }
    }
    public int getTabId(int tab_id) {
        return tab_idd;
    }
```

I do not know how I must Receive **tab_idd** from the **activity**

Comment: Create 1 method in fragment class. like
public void setPosition(int position){}

Now inside onTabSelected() method, when you assign value to tab_idd.
then using fragment reference, call setPosition(tab_idd) ;

Comment: I try this with one problem . I succeeded to sent random data ,but are there any Existing method to get the position or id of selected tab to get it and send it ? **I can not get the position of tab**

Comment: Using tab.getPosition(), you  will get selected tab position.
Please clarify your requirement, what exactly you want